# Why does my URI return the correct JSON in my browser, but not in from my httpClient?

Tags: android, json, django, httpclient, android-ion

I'm relatively new to Django and RESTful APIs.

I'm writing an Android Application that executes a GET request to my API, which I've set up using Django and Postgresql. I am executing this request asynchronously using the Ion library. I dont think Ion is a problem, because this code works when I try to GET from sample URIs like http://ip.jsontest.com/.  My code looks like this.

```
    public class ConnectToBackend {

    //Contains public static functions

    public static void getAllQuestions(final Context mcontext){


        Ion.with(mcontext)
        .load("bhive.herokuapp.com/api/questions")
        .asJsonObject()
        .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
           @Override
            public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
               // this is called back onto the ui thread, no Activity.runOnUiThread or Handler.post necessary.

               Log.d("ConnectToBackend", "getAllQuestions called");
               if (e != null) {
                   Toast.makeText(mcontext, "Error loading questions " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   Log.d("ConnectToBackend", e.toString());
                   return;
               }
               else{
                   Log.d("connectToBackend", "Received JSON array for getAllQuestions");
                   Log.d("connectToBackend", "jsonObject is " + result.toString());
                   return;
 }
            }
        });
        return;
    }}
```

As you can see, the URI is bhive.herokuapp.com/api/questions. When I try this in my browser, it returns the JSON string that I expect. However, when I try to get with this code, I expect the same JSON string but instead I get the exception:

```
java.lang.Exception: Invalid URI
```

Why is it that my browser returns the expected JSON but when I try this URI like this, it doesn't work? How is my URI different than from a sample URI like http://ip.jsontest.com/, which returns the same thing on my browser? Perhaps I have a conceptual shortfall somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URI is missing a scheme.  Try using `http://bhive.herokuapp.com/api/questions` instead.  The `http` is important.

Comment: Damn, I'm an idiot. Thanks. For some reason when I tried 
 "http://bhive.herokuapp.com/api/questions"
on my browser, it truncated it to http://bhive.herokuapp.com/api/questions/, so I didnt think of changing it.

edit - in fact, it's doing it here, how weird. I enter the http:, but it just disappears when I enter.

Comment: Yeah that's a Chrome thing.  But if you copy and paste it out of the URL bar it seems to add the http back on (for me, anyway).